# Convolution operation using FFT in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, fft, convolution

I want to compute the convolution operation using FFT.

Apply FFT to the two input tensors and generate output tensors using element-wise multiplication. This output tensor is then subjected to IFFT to produce the final output.

The code below is the pseudo code I wrote.

input tensors:

```py
import torch
a = torch.tensor([0, 1, 2, 3])
b = torch.tensor([1, 2])
```

pseudo code:

```py
fft_a = torch.fft.fft(a)
fft_b = torch.fft.fft(b, n=4)
out = fft_a * fft_b
out = torch.fft.ifft(out)
```

expected output:

```py
print(out.real)
>>> tensor([2., 5., 8.])
```

real output:

```py
print(out.real)
>>> tensor([6., 1., 4., 7.])
```

How can I perform the convolution operation using FFT?

Comment: That is the convolution operation. Your expected output is not the result of the convolution, but of the correlation.